# Find all natural numbers which are multiplies of 3 and 5 recursively

Tags: ruby

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

```
def multiples_of(number)
  number = number.to_f - 1.0
  result = 0
  if (number / 5.0) == 1 || (number / 3.0) == 1
    return result = result + 5.0 + 3.0
  elsif (number % 3).zero? || (number % 5).zero?
    result += number 
    multiples_of(number-1)
  else 
    multiples_of(number-1)
  end
  return result
end

p multiples_of(10.0)
```

My code is returning 9.0 rather than 23.0.

Comment: The word "recursively" only appears in the title. Is that a requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. Most importantly, you're making recursive calls but you aren't *combining* their results in any way.

Let's step through what happens with an input of 10.

You assign `number = number.to_f - 1.0` which will equal 9.

Then you reach the `elsif (number % 3).zero? || (number % 5).zero?` condition which is true, so you call `result += number` and `multiples_of(number-1)`.

However, you're *discarding* the return value of the recursive call and call `return result` no matter what. So, your recursion doesn't have any impact on the return value. And for any input besides 3 or 5 you will *always* return `input-1` as the return value. That's why you're getting 9.

Here's an implementation which works, for comparison:

```
def multiples_of(number)
  number -= 1
  return 0 if number.zero?
  if number % 5 == 0 || number % 3 == 0
    number + multiples_of(number)
  else
    multiples_of(number)
  end
end

puts multiples_of(10)
# => 23
```

Note that I'm calling `multiples_of(number)` instead of `multiples_of(number - 1)` because you're already decrementing the input on the function's first line. You don't need to decrement twice - that would cause you to only process every other number e.g. 9,7,5,3

### *explanation*

to step throgh the recursion a bit to help you understand it. Let's say we have an input of 4.

We first decrement the input so number=3. Then we hits the `if number % 5 == 0 || number % 3 == 0` condition so we return `number + multiples_of(number)`.

What does `multiples_of(number)` return? Now we have to evaluate the next recursive call. We decrement the number so now we have number=2. We hit the `else` block so now we'll return `multiples_of(number)`.

We do the same thing with the next recursive call, with number=1. This `multiples_of(1)`. We decrement the input so now we have number=0. This matches our base case so finally we're done with recursive calls and can work up the stack to figure out what our actual return value is.

For an input of `6` it would look like so:

```
multiples_of(6)
 \
  5 + multiples_of(5)
       \
        multiples_of(4)
         \
          3 + multiples_of(3)
               \
                multiples_of(2)
                 \
                  multiples_of(1)
                   \
                    multiples_of(0)
                     \
                      0
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to break down where i went wrong. Looking at your solution I follow it up until the point there's no variable to store the result. I just can't wrap my head around how it sums this. Does the return value of each method call get stored in memory and then summed?

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for clarifying for me that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

### Using Core Methods to Select & Sum from a Range

It's not entirely clear what you really want to do here. This is clearly a homework assignment, so it's probably intended to get you to think in a certain way about whatever the lesson is. If that's the case, refer to your lesson plan or ask your instructor.

That said, if you restrict the set of possible input values to integers and use iteration rather than recursion, you can trivially solve for this using [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-select) on an exclusive [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Range.html), and then calling [Array#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-sum) on the intermediate result. For example:

```
(1...10).select { |i| i.modulo(3).zero? || i.modulo(5).zero? }.sum
#=> 23

(1...1_000).select { |i| i.modulo(3).zero? || i.modulo(5).zero? }.sum
#=> 233168
```

Leave off the #sum if you want to see all the selected values. In addition, you can create your own custom validator by comparing your logic to an expected result. For example:

```
def valid_result? range_end, checksum
  (1 ... range_end).select do |i|
    i.modulo(3).zero? || i.modulo(5).zero?
  end.sum.eql? checksum
end

valid_result? 10, 9
#=> false

valid_result? 10, 23
#=> true

valid_result? 1_000, 233_168
#=> true
```

Comment: thanks Todd. That's a cool answer to compare with I've never seen `select` before. I was trying to solve this recursively to practice my recursive problem solving

Answer (score 1):

The desired result can be obtained from a closed-form expression. That is, no iteration is required.

Suppose we are given a positive integer `n` and wish to compute the sum of all positive numbers that are multiples of `3` that do not exceed `n`.

```
1*3 + 2*3 +...+ m*3 = 3*(1 + 2 +...+ m)
```

where

```
m = n/3
```

`1 + 2 +...+ m` is the sum of an algorithmic expression, given by:

```
m*(1+m)/2
```

We therefore can write:

```
def tot(x,n)
  m = n/x
  x*m*(1+m)/2
end
```

For example,

```
tot(3,9)  #=> 18 (1*3 + 2*3 + 3*3)
tot(3,11) #=> 18 
tot(3,12) #=> 30 (18 + 4*3)
tot(3,17) #=> 45 (30 + 5*3)

tot(5,9)  #=> 5  (1*5)
tot(5,10) #=> 15 (5 + 2*5)
tot(5,14) #=> 15 
tot(5,15) #=> 30 (15 + 3*5)
```

The sum of numbers no larger than `n` that are multiple of `3`'s and `5`'s is therefore given by the following:

```
def sum_of_multiples(n)
  tot(3,n) + tot(5,n) - tot(15,n)
end
```

`- tot(15,n)` is needed because the first two terms double-count numbers that are multiples of `15`.

```
sum_of_multiples(9)         #=> 23 (3 + 6 + 9 + 5)
sum_of_multiples(10)        #=> 33 (23 + 2*5)
sum_of_multiples(11)        #=> 33
sum_of_multiples(12)        #=> 45 (33 + 4*3) 
sum_of_multiples(14)        #=> 45 
sum_of_multiples(15)        #=> 60 (45 + 3*5)
sum_of_multiples(29)        #=> 195 
sum_of_multiples(30)        #=> 225 
sum_of_multiples(1_000)     #=> 234168 
sum_of_multiples(10_000)    #=> 23341668 
sum_of_multiples(100_000)   #=> 2333416668 
sum_of_multiples(1_000_000) #=> 233334166668
```

Comment: Christian, I misunderstood the question so have revised my answer.